# List of windows path in configparse file in python

Tags: python, configparser

I am writting a script to backup a list of paths, inspired by https://github.com/Johanndutoit/Zip-to-FTP-Backup/blob/master/backup_to_ftp.py

So I have an ini file

```
[folders]
/home/david/docs
/home/david/images
/home/david/videos

[ftp]
username=etc
password=pwd
```

The code to read it is:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.optionxform = lambda option: option  # preserve case for letters
config.read('backupcfg.ini')

filelistings = [] # All Files that will be added to the Archive
# Add Files From Locations
for folder in config.options("folders"):
    filelistings.append(str(folder.strip("'")))
```

The problem is I can't find a way to read it as raw when I'm running it on windows, with folders like

```
[folders]
Z:\Desktop\winpython
```

I can't scape the backslash. I've ended up including it as:

```
filelistings = [r'Z:\docs\winpython', r'Z:\images\family']
```

Is there any way to write the paths in the ini? Can't find a way to read config.options("folders") to return raw.

Thank you for your help!

I have tried to add the path straight to the tar:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config.optionxform = lambda option: option  # preserve case for letters
    config.read('backupcfg.ini')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    zipname = 'backup.' + now.strftime("%Y.%m.%d") + '.tgz'
    
    with tarfile.open(zipname, "w:gz") as tar:
        for name in config.options("folders"):
            print ("Adding "+name)
            tar.add(str(name))
```

Which reports can't find filename: 'Z'
Is there any way to access that information as it is, with ?

Comment: Why do you say Perl and tag Perl when this is Python?

Comment: 1. You could always use `/`. DOS and Windows have always accepted `/` as a dir sep. But, 2. You don't want to escape the `\ `. `\ ` is escaped in string literals to create a string without the escape. ConfigParser surely produces the string as-is.

Comment: Ugh, you are right, it's Python - my mistake.
My idea is to let the user simply copy and paste paths in the text file as they come out of the file browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea for this answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25207455/9705687). The problem isn't with the slashes. It's with the colon (:). By default, Configparser uses `=` and `:` as delimiters. But you can specify other delimiters to use instead.

backupcfg.ini

```
[folders]
/home/david/docs
Z:\Desktop\winpython
```

python code

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True, delimiters=(','))
config.optionxform = lambda option: option  # preserve case for letters
config.read('backupcfg.ini')

for folder in config.options("folders"):
    print(folder)
```

output:

```
/home/david/docs
Z:\Desktop\winpython
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. That solves it. Quite obvious, once you know it.